# how to ProxyPass Wildcard local virtualhost subdomain with apache

Tags: node.js, apache

So I have locally developed Node.js app. I made apache virtual host locally to test the subdomain feature. Let's say the domain is `bloggin.fun` so every user will had their subdomain. `alexis.bloggin.fun` etc. How do I use the wildcard subdomain then proxy pass it to desired URL.

My current setup that I also follow from Stack Overflow gave me chrome not found error. Not redirected to the `localhost:4040/auth`

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName bloggin.fun
            ServerAlias hplus.onlocal
            ProxyPass / http://localhost:4040/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4040/
        </VirtualHost>


        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAlias *.bloggin.fun
            ProxyPass / http://localhost:4040/blog
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4040/blog
        </VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts` are look like this

```
127.0.0.1 bloggin.fun
```

What do I do wrong here? How to proxypass subdomain wildcard with apache? So when I access `alexis.bloggin.fun` will be proxy-ed to 'http:localhost:4040/auth'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/etc/hosts` is evaluated verbatim, and no recursion takes place - this is quite unlike DNS, where you have recursive resolvers.

To test subdomains, you need to specify their resolution as well:

```
127.0.0.1 bloggin.fun alexis.bloggin.fun tom.bloggin.fun freddie.bloggin.fun
```

Comment: Aaaha didn't know that. So I should use dns tools like dnsmasq

Comment: @mandaputtra You can use DNS tools, but honestly I think it's overkill for testing - just make up some subdomains, put them there and test with that. You may not need every subdomain imaginable to resolve, if you document the expected set of names that must work for e2e tests to pass.